# ELException when parsing a conditional expression in the style property of h:inputText

Tags: jsf, el

I'm having a problem with one of my custom JSF components. My component is called `inputTextCustom`.

In one of the pages that uses this custom component, I have :

```
<s:inputTextCustom length="400px"/>
```

And within my custom component's definition, I use a `h:inputText` as follows:

```
<ui:composition>
....
....
<h:inputText style="width:#{empty length ? 500px : length}" />
....
....
</ui:composition>
```

But, I get the following exception:

```
javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: width:#{empty length ? 500px : length}
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:125)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:150)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:194)
    at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:68)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.TagAttribute.getValueExpression(TagAttribute.java:256)
    ... 119 more
Caused by: org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "?" "? "" at line 1, column 22.
Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    ">" ...
    "gt" ...
    "<" ...
    "lt" ...
    ">=" ...
    "ge" ...
    "<=" ...
    "le" ...
    "==" ...
    "eq" ...
    "!=" ...
    "ne" ...
    "&&" ...
    "and" ...
    "||" ...
    "or" ...
    "*" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "/" ...
    "div" ...
    "%" ...
    "mod" ...

    at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.generateParseException(ELParser.java:2142)
    at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.jj_consume_token(ELParser.java:2024)
    at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.DeferredExpression(ELParser.java:113)
    at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.CompositeExpression(ELParser.java:40)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:93)
    ... 123 more
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to represent string values in EL, you need to explicitly quote them.

```
<h:inputText style="width:#{empty length ? '500px' : length}" />
```

Double quotes are also syntactically valid, but that usually doesn't mix very well with the syntax highlighter of the average editor (also not of the one here on SO) when the expression is inlined in a tag attribute value which is by itself enclosed in double quotes.

```
<h:inputText style="width:#{empty length ? "500px" : length}" />
```

Comment: I see now where I went wrong. Thanks for answering my newbie question! :)